# js works in opera, but do not works in any other browser

Tags: javascript

There is a animation after click on the marker. Why this works in Opera, but do not work in any other browser? Is it something with rendering engines presto and webkit? I can't solve it myself, please help.

http://turie.eu/02/

(all of the code is in one index.html file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying with Chromium I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object http://turie.eu/02/clouds.swf has no method 'click'
```

To simulate a click event you need to do something like this:

```
function fireEvent(element, event){
  if (document.createEventObject){
    /* for IE */
    return element.fireEvent('on' + event, document.createEventObject());
  }else{
    /* for other browsers */
    var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    evt.initEvent(event, true, true);
  }
  return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, WoLpH, I get the same error, but I havent find something useful to solve it myself. Could you, please, write some instructions how to implement your code? If I understand it right, I have to use your code instead of this..
google.maps.event.addListener(markerName, 'click', function() {    
    //document.getElementById("neco").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click(); 
})    thank you in advance

Comment: @culter: You should be able to use `fireEvent(document.getElementById("neco").getElementsByTagName("a")[0], 'click');`